# How to identify the cause of an app crash (Apple)

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, testflight

I am currently testing my app via TestFlight and have had a report of a crash. I've been looking at the code and trying to determine where the crash occurred and what the cause is but I'm stuck.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x180973d0c __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x198164ee4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x180a44750 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:147)
3   UIKitCore                       0x183ac7f34 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 268 (UIResponder.m:685)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x18090d60c ___forwarding___ + 1472 (NSForwarding.m:3577)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x18090c81c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
6   UIKitCore                       0x1830b20b4 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96 (UIApplication.m:5378)
7   UIKitCore                       0x1831d120c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 124 (UIControl.m:871)
8   UIKitCore                       0x182f6743c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 352 (UIControl.m:942)
9   UIKitCore                       0x182cafd20 -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 408 (UIControl.m:543)
10  UIKitCore                       0x182d6ded8 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 6708 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:0)
11  UIKitCore                       0x182d9ee74 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 736 (UIGestureEnvironment.m:1332)
12  UIKitCore                       0x182dab978 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4344 (UIWindow.m:3272)
13  UIKitCore                       0x182f4c504 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 892 (UIApplication.m:11975)
14  UIKitCore                       0x182d80974 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 8148 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2294)
15  UIKitCore                       0x182d75838 __processEventQueue + 6544 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2600)
16  UIKitCore                       0x182d7ac54 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 168 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2672)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x1809944ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1972)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1809a461c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2016)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x1808e6824 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1808ebef8 __CFRunLoopRun + 768 (CFRunLoop.c:2951)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x1808ff240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
22  GraphicsServices                0x1a13cf988 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2200)
23  UIKitCore                       0x1830ff41c -[UIApplication _run] + 1080 (UIApplication.m:3511)
24  UIKitCore                       0x182e98b88 UIApplicationMain + 336 (UIApplication.m:5064)
25  Here                            0x100d88afc main + 68 (SelectionViewController.swift:14)
26  dyld                            0x100fac3d0 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

I have looked at various resources but I'm still stuck:

1. I've looked into the execution type (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-language-exception-crashes)
2. I have looked into Zombies but nothing is showing (https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/dev612e6956)

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated - thank you.

Comment: what's the code at SelectionViewController.swift:14?

Comment: Line 14 is: `import UIKit`

Comment: it's an odd one. we don't have enough info to help unfortunately. There is a call to an undefined function, obviously. I would look for an unconnected interface item.